# Connection between an .NET application on the host and a spark-streaming application in a docker container via a socket

Tags: .net, docker, sockets, spark-streaming

I need to make two applications. The .net application will send json from the host, and the spark-streaming application in the docker container will receive this data via a socket and process it. But I don't know how to establish a connection between the host and the docker container so that the container receives information from the host application. Please tell me in general terms how to do this

I tried sending data to the container on the port that is specified in the docker-compose file. But there is no connection

Answer (score 0):

If you only specified one port in the compose file, then the host port used is random. You need to specify a host port as well to reliably connect i.e.:

```yaml
ports:
 - "8000:8000"
```

[Docs on the ports syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)